# Is it halal if I add some fees on the fees which the consultant has already set?

Tags: halal-haram

I work in an IT company, and sometimes I get involved into admission consultant, wherein my friend is actual admission consultant and if anyone comes to me to get admission in any college. I refer them to my friend. I get the quotation from my friend and tell the candidate the fees I have given including my fees.

For example: If my friend tells me X amount then I go and tell the candidate X+Y amount, where Y is my fees and the candidate is not aware of the Y amount.

Is this kind of earning halal in Islam?

Comment: What is your part of the product? Are you only handing the quotation? Are you getting paid already by 'your friend'?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the only thing to watch for is Riba. You should be paid for adding value and the candidate should be willingly paying for this added value.

Let's say that the price your friend charges is $1000. If you take $1200 from the candidate directly and don't tell him that you're taking extra, then it's arguably Riba.

If you take $1000 from the candidate and your friend gives you a 20% referral commission of $200, that should be fine because the candidate would still get the same price if they went to him directly.

You can also add value. For example, the registration for the course might be difficult and you could make it clear to the candidate that you're charging higher because you help them with registration. Or you could tell them that you know someone who can solve the problem but want to be paid $200 for the information.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely haram to lie to someone, specially when a transaction is taking place. You're not an admission consultant, and you're pretending to be one. Instead of charging the client, why don't you charge your friend for bringing him a client? That would be more fair, just and in that case you wouldn't be lying, that is an alternative for you to think about.

> The Prophet said, “The biggest of the Great Sins are: To join others in worship with Allah, to be undutiful to one’s own parents, and to give a false witness.” He repeated it thrice, or said, “….a false statement,” and kept on repeating that warning till we wished he would stop saying it ( Bukhari: Vol. 9, Book 84, Hadith 54)

Answer (score -1):

A guideline hadith for this sort of thing is:

> عن النواس بن سمعان -رضي الله عنه- عن النبي -صلى الله عليه وسلم- قال:
>   ((البر حسن الخلق، والإثم ما حاك في نفسك، وكرهت أن يطلع عليه الناس))
>   رواه مسلم

The body of the hadith is roughly translates to:

> *"Righteousness is good morality, and sin is that which wavers in your consciousness, and which you would hate for other people to find out
>   about"* (Muslim)

I don't claim to be an expert in halal vs. haram, so I would ask you to look within yourself: would you have problems with the client/candidate knowing about this arrangement? Hope this helps.